# Law of total probability - Continuous conditioned on discrete?

Tags: probability, distributions

Let $Y \sim f_Y (y)$ be a strictly continuous r.v.

Let $S \sim p(s)$ be a strictly discrete r.v.

Can you write the density $f_Y (y)$ as

$$f_Y (y) = \sum_S f(y|S=s)p(s)$$

I know the law of total probability holds when both $Y$ and $S$ are continuous random variables. But what if the conditioning r.v. is discrete, while $Y$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than close this question I'll leave an answer in the off chance it helps someone in future.

According to [Karlin & Taylor's Introduction to Stochastic modelling](https://matap.dmae.upm.es/WebpersonalBartolo/Probabilidad/KarlinTaylorIntrodStochModeling.pdf), page 71, for continuous $x$ and discrete $n$, one can indeed write

$$f(x) =\sum_n f(x|n)p(n)$$

Comment: This is the idea behind a mixture distribution.  $p(n)$ are the $\pi_n$, and it is a sum of $N$ continuous densities.  I think you asked pretty much the same question a while back.